# Can i add jshell repl (java 9) to vscode's terminal panel?

Tags: java, terminal, visual-studio-code, jshell

New to vscode, search returns nothing.

I'd like to add jshell to the terminal window. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) the `shellArgs` for the integrated terminal to launch `jshell`. On mac, this would be:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [
    "-l",
    "-c",
    "jshell"
]
```